# Sonarqube on Port 80

Tags: sonarqube

Installed Sonarqube as a Windows service and trying to access the application via port 80 instead of default port 9000.
Tried modifying the sonar.web.port in sonar.properties file to have port 80 using this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server and restarted the service. But after each restart the application is accessible only via port 9000. Request goes to port 9000 when checked in the Access logs.

```
# The default value is root context (empty value). 
sonar.web.context= 
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections.Default value is 9000. 
sonar.web.port=80
```

Comment: Hi, could you give us the line you've added in sonar.properties ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Here it is 

`# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=80`

Comment: Thanks, but it's hard to read like this... Are you sure the sonar.web.port=80 is not included in the previous line ?

Comment: Yes sonar.web.port=80 is on a separate line. @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: Then I've no idea what happen...

Comment: try uninstall and install the service and check if the port 80 is not in use. Regards

Comment: Perhaps it could also be a security issue... in other operating system like unix the port 80 cannot be bound using a non-root user due to security restrictions.